# allow a user to run specific monit action

Tags: linux, monit

I have installed monit for many applications with the root user. 
One of the applications is started with a non-root user account.

Unfortunately, when I 
 update my app, I also need to restart it. My update process uses the non-root user (I use capistrano to udpate my app)

Since Monit is checking this app and the update process is done with the non-root user. In order to restart the app, the non-root user kills the app and monit restarts it.

I would like to allow the non-root user to be allowed to only restart this specific app. This user shouldn't be aloud to run other monit related actions.

Is there a way to allow a user run a specific monit action, even if he is not the owner of the monitrc ?

Comment: If you want to allow a non-root user to execute privileged command, you can use `sudoers` file.

Comment: Is their a way to achieve this using monit config instead ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an entry to `/etc/sudoers`...

```
%non-root-group ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/monit
```

or

```
non-root-user ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/monit
```

or

```
non-root-user ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/monit reload # to give a specific Monit command.
```

Comment: Is their a way to achieve this using monit config instead ?

Comment: Finally granted my user this privilege, but I am still looking for a way to achieve this from a monit config point

Answer (score 0):

According to https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONFIGURATION-EXAMPLES, you can use a configuration with

> start program ...as uid "capistrano" and gid "users"

Maybe this does what you want?